# How to calculate perimeter of Polygon with missing the length of one side?

Tags: polygons

I have following sides(PQRST) of a Polygon where PQ=13, QR=22, RS=8, ST=?, PT= 10 ... i need to find out ST? i don't have any angle i just have the shape? And for calculating perimeter i need to find out the ST length of polygon!

[This figure is showing all the sides that are given and side that i need to calculate for getting its perimeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eiw7s.jpg).

Comment: Presumably, all the angles that look like right angles are supposed to be taken to be right angles, in which case a little insight and a use of Pythagoras should answer your questions.

Comment: I found its solution done by somebody using Pythagoras Theorem. and he got the missing side with length 13 and calculated perimeter 66 if am not wrong. But, i don't know how he has done. Because i don't have much knowledge about polygons and new here. I need some sort of a helping hand to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you draw perpendicular from $T$ to $QR$ and from $S$ to $PQ$ ? Pythagoras Theorem.

Complete rectangles by drawing sides I told you about. Use the fact that opposite sides of rectangles are equal You should be able to get a right angled triangle with hypotenuse as $ST$ and other 2 sides as $13-8$ and $22-10$.

Comment: I found its solution done by somebody using Pythagoras Theorem. and he got the missing side with length 13 and calculated perimeter 66 if am not wrong. But, i don't know how he has done. Because i don't have much knowledge about polygons and new here

Comment: @Nomi Get it now?

Comment: @Nomi Can't u just think of this polygon as some rectangles and a triangle put together and deleted all lines except the perimeter? You just gotta reconstruct those lines which question maker deleted.

Comment: thanks dear it solved the purpose :)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

We can make use of the symmetry here and use Pythogoras theorm to Solve:

Observe that:

```
QR = PO = 22 {Opposite sides of a rectangle}
PT + TO = 22
TO = 22- PT = 22 - 10 = 12
```

Similarly,

```
PQ = OR = 13  {Opposite sides of a rectangle}
OS + SR = 13
OS = 13 - SR = 13 - 8 = 5
```

Now In right Traingle TOS, rt angled at O,

```
$TO^2 + OS^2 = ST^2  {Using Pythogoras Theorm}$
$12^2 + 5^2 = TS^2$
$TS^2 = 144 + 25 = 169$
```

***Hence, TS = 13***

Now you can find the perimeter.

Comment: Great way to answer this :)

Comment: @Nomi thanks, if its useful, you can vote this up.

Comment: i did but,.. i need 15 reputation for doing it :P sorry